# VMware - Not printing in order

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers, printing, vmware-workstation

I am using vmware workstation 7. Guest is Windows XP. The host OS is Windows 7. When I queue the printer with multiple documents, the printer doesn't print in order. It seems to print the smaller size in data of documents first. The printer is an HP printer.

This is what I have tried so far:

- I have tested this on the host machine, and it works fine.
- I have tested this on other host machines(XP Windows7), and it works fine.
- I have tested other HP printers
- I have tested it another another guest OS Windows 7
- I have tested different drivers

Thanks in advance for any help on this one!

Comment: Your system for hosting vmware workstation is what?

Comment: windows 7 32 bit

Comment: have you checked which printer drivers you are using? are they the same in the VM as on the Host machine?

Comment: is this printer on a print server?

Comment: @jth41 No it is not a printer on a print server

Answer (score 3):

Its a problem with spooling. the print jobs are being sent in the correct order and then being arranged based on when spooling finishes. bigger more complicated print jobs take longer to spool.

Perhaps you could create a solution to monitor and manipulate the printing steps.

and this code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51085/Monitor-jobs-in-a-printer-queue-NET

Comment: Spooling is not the issue. VMware is the issue. I guess the question is how do you change the "way" VMware prints your document.

Answer (score 3):

You should try correcting the problem through the the printers settings.

Try setting it to print without spooling.

As shown in this awesomely recorded video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wJS0r6Fu-I

Comment: @ jth41 I have tried this, nice video btw. The documents are still being printed out of order.